# Excel pivot table sort by values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, sorting

I've done quite a bit of searching but cant find working instructions on how to sort a pivot table in Excel by a field that has been placed in the Values area.

The best I've been able to come up with is to copy and paste values to another worksheet and do the sort on the flat data set.

But, it seems there must be a way to sort by Values field within the pivot table.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To sort by Values in a PivotTable, right-click on one Value cell, hover over Sort, and click the type of sort to perform.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work.  It takes a few seconds to refresh and then the data is returned in the exact same order.  My data source is an SSAS cube and the fields I want to sort on are calculated metrics within the cube.  I dont think it should matter, but then again, the sort should work.